# Best way to handle storing (possibly NULL) char * in a std::string

Tags: c++, stl, char

```
class MyClass
{
 public:
  void setVar(const char *str);
 private:
  std::string mStr;
  int maxLength; //we only store string up to this length
};
```

What's the best approach to implement setVar when the external code is quite likely to pass in NULL for an empty string (and cannot be changed)? I currently do something a bit like:

```
void MyClass::setVar(const char *str)
{
 mStr.assign(str ? str : "",maxLength);
}
```

But it seems kind of messy. ideas?

Comment: I suppose you'll be reading the value of the `string` somewhere else. Does this code need a `char const*` or a `string`?

Comment: In what way do you think it's messy?

Comment: @Thomas, why do you ask? I think either way it's best my new class uses STL... in fact I'm converting it from storing C strings because it makes copying the object much more error-prone... a new field is added and by default is not copied!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you posted is incorrect, as it will always read `maxLength` characters from the source string. In particular, this means it will read past the end of the empty string when `str` is NULL. This will work instead, assuming `str` is null-terminated:

```
void MyClass::setVar(const char *str)
{
    if (str==NULL)
        mStr.clear();
    else
        mStr.assign(str, std::min(strlen(str), maxLength));
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I just realised in debugging that string::assign doesn't work how I expected.

Answer (score 2):

```
void MyClass::setVar(const char *str) 
{ 
    if (str) {
       mStr.assign(str, str + std::min(strlen(str), maxLength) ); 
    } else {
       mStr = "";
    }
}
```